# Vector Recording Intervals in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

Hope you are doing good.

I would like to enable vector recording on my Omnet++ Simulation to record event logs for each second instead of milliseconds.

Could you please advise which syntax should I use to record for each seconds ?

```
**.vector-recording-intervals = <syntax>
```

Awaiting for a response.

Regards,

Azhar

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the `vector-recording-intervals` is slightly different. That parameter gives us an opportunity to decide *when* recording vectors is enabled. It should be noticed, that by default recording vectors is turned on for the whole duration the simulation.
Let's consider an example:

```
**.vector-recording-intervals = 10s..30s, 100s..150s
```

It means, that vectors will be recorded **only** from t=10s to 30s and from t=100s to 150s.

And the frequency of recording values into vector depends on the frequency of calling `emit()` or `record()` in your code.